# CSS BUG: Arrowed Progress Bar height mismatch

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement an Arrowed Progress bar, I'm facing a CSS error. When I increase the height of content the appended arrows don't increase in their height.
Try to run the code spinnet and you will understand the error I'm facing. The error is based on CSS and triangle/arrow progress bar content height

```css
ol.steps {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Liberation Sans', Verdana, 'Verdana Ref', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  counter-reset: li;
}

ol.steps li {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  background: #dae4eb;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 43px;
}

ol.steps li:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 100%;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #dae4eb;
  border-width: 19px;
  margin-top: -19px;
}

ol.steps li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

ol.steps li:first-child span {
  padding: 9px;
}

ol.steps li:first-child span:after {
  border: none;
}

ol.steps li:last-child:after {
  border-width: 0;
}

ol.steps li span {
  display: block;
  padding: 9px 28px 9px 9px;
}

ol.steps li span:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: solid #dae4eb;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-width: 19px;
  margin-top: -19px;
}

ol.steps li span:before {
  content: counter(li) " ";
  counter-increment: li;
}

ol.steps>li {
  float: left;
}

ol.steps li.current {
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0078b4;
}

ol.steps li.current:after {
  border-left-color: #0078b4;
}


ol.steps li.current span:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

ol.steps li.step1 {
  z-index: 9;
}

ol.steps li.step2 {
  z-index: 8;
}

ol.steps li.step3 {
  z-index: 7;
}

ol.steps li.step4 {
  z-index: 6;
}

ol.steps li.step5 {
  z-index: 5;
}

ol.steps li.step6 {
  z-index: 4;
}

ol.steps li.step7 {
  z-index: 3;
}

ol.steps li.step8 {
  z-index: 2;
}

ol.steps li.step9 {
  z-index: 1;
}

ol.steps li.step10 {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol class="steps">
  <li class="step1 current"><span><br>Submitted</span></li>
  <li class="step2"><span><br>.</span></li>
  <li class="step3"><span><br>.</span></li>
  <li class="step4"><span><br>.</span></li>
  <li class="step5"><span><br>.</span></li>
</ol>
```

Error image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYf8i.png)

I Tried many CSS tweaks but dint succeed in matching the heights
Required Result: [Required Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W99OE.png)

Comment: Could you show us an image of what you want the result to look like?

Comment: What are your browser support requirements? I'm wondering if `clip-path` might be better than border-triangles.

Comment: This article might help you: https://css-tricks.com/oh-the-many-ways-to-make-triangular-breadcrumb-ribbons/

Comment: @mfluehr I have added the required result image

Answer (score 0):

I modified into your css few lines of code and draw progress arrow with same height.

```css
*, *:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
ol.steps {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Liberation Sans', Verdana, 'Verdana Ref', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  counter-reset: li;
}
ol.steps li {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  background: #dae4eb;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  transition: 300ms;
  float: left;
}
ol.steps li:before, ol.steps li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #dae4eb;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: -18px;
  transition: 300ms;
}
ol.steps li:before{
  right: auto;
  left: -40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
ol.steps li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
ol.steps li span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 9px 28px 9px 9px;
  z-index: 50;
  pointer-events: none;
}
ol.steps li span:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  display: block;
}
ol.steps li.current, ol.steps li:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background: #0078b4;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ol.steps li.current:after, ol.steps li:hover:after {
  background-color: #0078b4
}
```

```html
<ol class="steps">
  <li class="step1 current"><span>Begin</span></li>
  <li class="step2"><span>ABC</span></li>
  <li class="step3"><span>BCD</span></li>
  <li class="step4"><span>CDE</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: How can I flatten the 1st Div left side and last div right side

Comment: Your CSS is not working on my page: https://imgur.com/NfHjGin

Comment: @TechFood I think you are using <br> tag in li so removed <br> tag.

Comment: @TechFood Check another example for fatten 1st & last list https://stackoverflow.com/a/64495107/7052927